# replace all the values in a string in lesser line of codes

Tags: python

I have a string = "12345678"
I wanted to replace each character of this string into text:

I have already built the dictionary(its my requirement). However, I do not know how to replace all of it.

The dictionary is build all I have to do is just loop string and then replace it with the value in the dictionary.

```
text = [string.replace(x, dictionary[x]) for x in string]
```

My current output:

it replaces one by one instead and then created 8 different element in the list with each element only one character is replace.

Example(Sorry I cant show much):

```
text = [one2345678, 1two345678, 12three45678...1234567eight]
```

I dont know why.

My expected output:

```
text= onetwothreefourfivesixseveneight
```

Comment: Could you share the dictionary too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

s='12345678'
d={
    '1':'one',
    '2':'two'
}
print(re.sub(r'\d',lambda x:d[x.group()],s))
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you are using a list comprehension instead try

```
string = "12345678"
text = ''
for x in string:
    text += dictionary[x]
```

or

```
text = "".join(dictionary[x] for x in string)
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression route that SmartManoj recommended is perfect if the thing you want to replace is more than one character, but if you're mapping single characters to arbitrary-length strings, then it's waaaaaay overkill.

You can instead use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) alongside [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

```
dictionary = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', ... }
mapping = str.maketrans(dictionary)

string = '12345678'
text = string.translate(mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension solution:

```
text_in = '12345678 and the rest is not in dic'
replace_dic = {
    '1': 'one',
    '2': 'two',
    '3': 'three',
    '4': 'four',
    '5': 'five',
    '6': 'six',
    '7': 'seven',
    '8': 'eight',
}

text_out = ''.join(replace_dic.get(c, c) for c in text_in)
print(text_out)  # 'onetwothreefourfivesixseveneight and the rest is not in dic'
```

EDIT: code edited per comment, and print converted to Python3.

Comment: `replace_dic[c] if c in replace_dic else c` is just `replace_dic.get(c, c)`